# Paypal Java SDK - trying to create encrypted button - doesn't work, can't find documentation

Tags: java, security, encryption, paypal

I recently got the book "Pro Paypal E-Commerce" by Damon Williams. Its a 2007 copy, so its to be expected that some things, like the code, would change over time.

I'm trying to get this code below to work. I downloaded the paypal_base.jar file and also the paypal_wpstoolkit.jar and put them into my lib folder under jakarta-tomcat (where all my other jars are). I'm having trouble compiling the code.

This code example comes from the book and also http://en.csharp-online.net/Encrypted_Website_Payments%E2%80%94Using_the_PayPal_Java_SDK

I modified it slightly.

```
import com.paypal.sdk.profiles.EWPProfile;
import com.paypal.sdk.profiles.ProfileFactory;

import com.paypal.wpstoolkit.services.EWPServices;

import com.paypal.sdk.exceptions.PayPalException;


    public class PaypalTest {


      // path to your PKCS12 file
      public static final String PKCS12 = "./Certs/my_pkcs12.p12";

      // path to PayPal's public certificate
      public static final String PAYPAL_CERT = "./Certs/paypal_cert_pem.txt";

      // use https://www.sandbox.paypal.com if testing
      //public static final String URL = "https://www.paypal.com";
      public static final String URL = "https://sandbox.paypal.com";

      public static void main (String args[]) {

        // Check to see if the user provided a password
        if (args.length != 1) {
          System.out.println("You must provide a password.");
          System.exit(0);
        }

        // password used to encrypt your PKCS12 files
        // obtained from the command line
        String USER_PASSWORD = args[0];


        // First we will create the EWPProfile object
        try {
          com.paypal.sdk.profiles.EWPProfile ewpProfile = ProfileFactory.createEWPProfile();

          ewpProfile.setCertificateFile(PKCS12);
          ewpProfile.setPayPalCertificateFile(PAYPAL_CERT);
          ewpProfile.setPrivateKeyPassword(USER_PASSWORD);
          ewpProfile.setUrl(URL);

          String buttonParameters = "cmd=_xclick\nbusiness=buyer@hotmail.com\nitem_name=vase\nitemprice=25.00";

          // Next we will create the EWPServices object
          // and tell it which EWPProfile object to use
          EWPServices ewpServices = new EWPServices();
          ewpServices.setEWPProfile(ewpProfile);

          // Finally we are ready to call the method to perform the button encryption
          String encryptedButton = ewpServices.encryptButton(buttonParameters.getBytes());

          System.out.println(encryptedButton);
        } catch (PayPalException ppe) {
          System.out.println("An exception occurred when creating the button.");
          ppe.printStackTrace();
        }       

    }

}//class
```

**The errors I'm getting during compilation are as follows -**

```
java:51: cannot find symbol
symbol: method setEWPProfile(com.paypal.sdk.profiles.EWPProfile)
location: class com.paypal.wpstoolkit.services.EWPServices
ewpServices.setEWPProfile(ewpProfile);


java:55: encryptButton(byte[],java.lang.String,java.lang.String.,java.lang.String.,java.lang.String) in com.paypal.wpstoolkit.services.EWPServices cannot be applied to (byte[])
ewpServices.encryptButton(buttonParameters.getBytes());
```

The `paypal_base jar` only has `NVPCallerServices.class` in it, and not `EWPServices`. EWPServices is in the `wpstoolkit jar`.

How do I fix my errors? I'm having trouble finding documentation on the paypal classes.

Comment: Do you have the API documentation? Is it somewhere we can see?

Comment: I've been looking on Paypal's site and can't find the documentation I need for their Java classes. That's a major part of why I can't fix my problem...

Comment: Yeah that's rediculous, how can they have an API without documentation. It has to be somewhere. Have you tried contacting them?

Comment: I put up a post awhile ago (https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Merchant-services/Having-problems-with-Paypal-Java-SDK-for-Encrypted-Website/m-p/279838/message-uid/279838#U279838) on their site, regarding their Java SDK and the deprecated classes - I hope it won't be too long before I get a response. If I don't hear from someone, I guess I could contact them through email?

Comment: They probably have a contact email, just say you are doing some development, companies are usually pretty helpful if they know you are making applications for their products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated Java SDK + API documenatation can be found [here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks):

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_Java_NVP_SDK.zip

Extract that .zip and open docs/index.html

That is where you can find all of the API documentation. It looks like you are trying to make calls to methods that no longer exist. Have a look through the new classes and see what will work for you.

Comment: I downloaded the Paypal Java SDK for Encryption of Website Payments. It keeps getting better for me...now there are deprecated classes being used by the ClientSide.java class - so I can't even compile it.

Comment: @katura, sounds like quite the mess. It may be best just to start from scratch with the new SDK + documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the SDK. I had so much trouble locating it on their silly website.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like with the newer API's Paypal want you to have all button code generated from their web service, as they seem to have removed the `EWPService` class from the SDK. But then I noticed they still provide the client side utility with with you can manually generate the code [here](https://www.paypalobjects.com/WEBSCR-640-20121028-1/en_US/dwnloads/java.zip). After a little tweaking, I got the code in there to do what I needed (encrypt an upload cart button locally).

Assuming you use Java 5+, just make sure you [this](http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk15on-147.jar) and [this](http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcpkix-jdk15on-147.jar) in your classpath. Now the code isn't perfect, as it contains a bunch of deprecated methods, but for such a trivial task as encrypting the button code, it works just fine.

```
public String getButtonEncryptionValue(String _data,
        String _privateKeyPath, String _certPath, String _payPalCertPath,
        String _keyPass) throws IOException, CertificateException,
        KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NoSuchProviderException, CertStoreException, CMSException {
    _data = _data.replace(',', '\n');
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509", "BC");

    // Read the Private Key
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(_privateKeyPath), _keyPass.toCharArray());

    String keyAlias = null;
    Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases();
    while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) {
        keyAlias = aliases.nextElement();
    }

    PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(keyAlias,
            _keyPass.toCharArray());

    // Read the Certificate
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) cf
            .generateCertificate(new FileInputStream(_certPath));

    // Read the PayPal Cert
    X509Certificate payPalCert = (X509Certificate) cf
            .generateCertificate(new FileInputStream(_payPalCertPath));

    // Create the Data
    byte[] data = _data.getBytes();

    // Sign the Data with my signing only key pair
    CMSSignedDataGenerator signedGenerator = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

    signedGenerator.addSigner(privateKey, certificate,
            CMSSignedDataGenerator.DIGEST_SHA1);

    ArrayList<X509Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<X509Certificate>();
    certList.add(certificate);
    CertStore certStore = CertStore.getInstance("Collection",
            new CollectionCertStoreParameters(certList));
    signedGenerator.addCertificatesAndCRLs(certStore);

    CMSProcessableByteArray cmsByteArray = new CMSProcessableByteArray(data);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    cmsByteArray.write(baos);
    System.out.println("CMSProcessableByteArray contains ["
            + baos.toString() + "]");

    CMSSignedData signedData = signedGenerator.generate(cmsByteArray, true,
            "BC");

    byte[] signed = signedData.getEncoded();

    CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator envGenerator = new CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator();
    envGenerator.addKeyTransRecipient(payPalCert);
    CMSEnvelopedData envData = envGenerator.generate(
            new CMSProcessableByteArray(signed),
            CMSEnvelopedDataGenerator.DES_EDE3_CBC, "BC");

    byte[] pkcs7Bytes = envData.getEncoded();

    return new String(DERtoPEM(pkcs7Bytes, "PKCS7"));

}

public static byte[] DERtoPEM(byte[] bytes, String headfoot) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream pemStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(pemStream);

    byte[] stringBytes = Base64.encode(bytes);

    System.out.println("Converting " + stringBytes.length + " bytes");

    String encoded = new String(stringBytes);

    if (headfoot != null) {
        writer.print("-----BEGIN " + headfoot + "-----\n");
    }

    // write 64 chars per line till done
    int i = 0;
    while ((i + 1) * 64 < encoded.length()) {
        writer.print(encoded.substring(i * 64, (i + 1) * 64));
        writer.print("\n");
        i++;
    }
    if (encoded.length() % 64 != 0) {
        writer.print(encoded.substring(i * 64)); // write remainder
        writer.print("\n");
    }
    if (headfoot != null) {
        writer.print("-----END " + headfoot + "-----\n");
    }
    writer.flush();
    return pemStream.toByteArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this is not to encrypt, but use an unencrypted button and then a hash trick to detect tampering. I explain this here with PHP, but you can translate to Java.

[How do I make a PayPal encrypted buy now button with custom fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14489512/105539)